# How can I make a responsive image grid using only flexbox?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, responsive-images

I'm starting my first full website project, I've been learning HTML and CSS for about a month now and I just got done learning the basics of flexbox. I was wondering if it's possible to create an image grid where the images resize themselves automatically as the browser window is resized using only flexbox, as that's all I know for now.

What I'm trying to recreate is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7PWf.jpg.). One large image on the left, with two smaller images stacked on top of each other to the right. When I shrink the browser, the images stay in place automatically resize themselves. Here's the [website](https://www.gasolinealleycoffee.com/) if you want to check it out live. Just scroll down a bit till you see it.

Here is my poor attempt on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5c1bfde7/10/). For some reason, jsfiddle is not displaying it they way it displays on my computer. The images on my computer are side by side, like how I sort of it want it, but it breaks onto the next line if I resize the window a tiny bit.

For those not wanting to deal with jsfiddle, here is the relevant HTML and CSS. I know it's a mess.

HTML:

```css
/* Section: Gallery */

#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: rgb(252, 246, 237);
  text-align: center;
}

.coffee-img-1 {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 5rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.coffee-img-2,
.coffee-img-3 {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 30px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

#gallery img:hover {
  animation-name: opacity-hover;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes opacity-hover {
  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Gallery -->
<section id="gallery">
  <div>
    <img class="coffee-img-1" src="https://i.imgur.com/58DZwQ2.jpg" alt="Table with coffee and pastries">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="coffee-img-2" src="https://i.imgur.com/hsSn85u.jpg" alt="Barista pulling two espresso shots">
    <img class="coffee-img-3" src="https://i.imgur.com/nmAId6V.jpg" alt="Barista brewing coffee with aeropress">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you need to rethink width and max-width into width and min-width, also the margins/paddings https://jsfiddle.net/xnh9tqko/ so alignements are squared when side by side or top bottom. object-fit might help to finalyze and crop image when ratio is not  coherent enough to fit the visual :)

Comment: @G-Cyr I didn't think of using min-width like that. Thanks for the tips, it's looking a lot better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you forgot to add the class `column` into the first div. Like this:

```
<!-- Gallery -->
<section id="gallery">
  <div class="column">
    <img class="coffee-img-1" src="https://i.imgur.com/58DZwQ2.jpg" alt="Table with coffee and pastries">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="coffee-img-2" src="https://i.imgur.com/hsSn85u.jpg" alt="Barista pulling two espresso shots">
    <img class="coffee-img-3" src="https://i.imgur.com/nmAId6V.jpg" alt="Barista brewing coffee with aeropress">
  </div>
</section>
```

To achieve this behavior you can change the `width` property for `max-width`. The `width` property forces the width to be fixed, while the `max-width` (and `min-width`) says "hey, even if my image it's bigger than that resizes it for the max width `x`"

Example:

https://codepen.io/icaromh/pen/jRopmp

**Docs:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Comment: I knew about the max-width stuff but it never occurred to me to add the column class to the other div. That instantly solved my problem and it makes so much sense. The images are resizing themselves like how I wanted without any issues. Thanks!